# Why do we set content view in onCreate() and not in onStart() or onResume()?

Tags: android

I've created a small program to set the content view on onResume() method instead of onCreate() and its working fine.

```
onResume()
{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As `onCreate()` of an Activity is called only once, this is the point where most initialization should go: calling `setContentView(int)` to inflate the activity's UI, using findViewById to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI, calling `managedQuery(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[], String)` to retrieve cursors for data being displayed, etc.

It is inefficient to set the content in `onResume()` or `onStart()` (which are called multiple times) as the `setContentView()` is a heavy operation.

Answer (score 5):

You don't setContentView in onStart or onResume because it's inefficient. Setting up the layout is a pretty heavyweight task. You have to parse the XML, create the Views, measurements, drawing, etc. It's the sort of task that you want to run at most once.

During the lifetime of your Activity class onCreate gets called exactly once. onResume and onStart will get called multiple times without your Activity getting destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

`onResume` you may call it serval times. `onCreate` is just one time. Try log sth in they and skip to other activity than back.

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to set the content in onResume() or onStart() (which are called multiple times) as the setContentView() is a heavy operation, also since it takes more time and oncreate is called way before than on resume, you should always set the UI only once in onCreate method